# How to call the Home Graph API with gRPC on Node.js

Tags: node.js, grpc, google-smart-home, grpc-node

Given the protocol buffers definition available at: https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/home/graph/v1/homegraph.proto

How can one call the [Home Graph API RPC endpoint](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/reference/rpc/google.home.graph.v1) using gRPC on Node.js to multiplex concurrent API method calls over a single connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [@grpc-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@grpc/grpc-js) in combination with [Application Default Credentials](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs#application-default-credentials) to initialize the credentials.

```
$ npm install @grpc/grpc-js
$ npm install google-auth-library
$ export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/service-account-key.json
```

```
const grpc = require('@grpc/grpc-js');
const { GoogleAuth } = require('google-auth-library');

async function getCredentials() {
  const sslCredentials = grpc.credentials.createSsl();
  const googleAuth = new GoogleAuth({
    scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/homegraph'
  });
  const authClient = await googleAuth.getClient();
  const callCredentials = grpc.credentials.createFromGoogleCredential(
      authClient
  );
  const credentials = grpc.credentials.combineChannelCredentials(
      sslCredentials,
      callCredentials
  );
  return credentials;
}
```

Use [google-proto-files](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-proto-files) with [@grpc/proto-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@grpc/proto-loader) to load the Home Graph service protobuf definition with its dependencies.

```
const protoLoader = require('@grpc/proto-loader');
const protos = require('google-proto-files');

async function getHomegraph() {
  const homegraphProto = await protoLoader.load(
      protos.getProtoPath('home/graph', 'v1', 'homegraph.proto'), {
        includeDirs: [protos.getProtoPath('..')]
      }
  );
  const homegraph = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(
      homegraphProto
  ).google.home.graph.v1;
  return homegraph;
}
```

And finally initialize client stubs to call the [HomeGraphApiService](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/reference/rpc/google.home.graph.v1#google.home.graph.v1.HomeGraphApiService) methods.

```
(async function() {
  const credentials = await getCredentials();
  const homegraph = await getHomegraph();

  const homegraphService = new homegraph.HomeGraphApiService(
      'homegraph.googleapis.com', credentials
  );

  homegraphService.sync({
    agentUserId: 'AGENT_USER_ID'
  }, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.log(result);
    }
  });

  // homegraphService.query();
  // homegraphService.requestSyncDevices();
  // homegraphService.reportStateAndNotification();
  // homegraphService.deleteAgentUser();
})();
```

Note that by default the `Channel` [implementation](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/blob/master/packages/grpc-js/src/subchannel-pool.ts#L127) will reuse existing channels from a global pool if the parameters (address, credentials and options) are the same. You can alter this behavior with the `grpc.use_local_subchannel_pool` [option](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/blob/bf2e5cb1dd25e43f53605d8de2b8e082072ec23e/packages/grpc-js/src/channel.ts#L221).